# Simple factory vs Factory method

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern, factory-method

Simple factory:
[image]

Factory method:

[image]

hey everyone. I am looking for the difference between simple factory and factory method.. I know the structural difference(images above), but I cant understand difference in use cases. for example, this is the explanation for factory method:

> In Factory Method pattern we will introduce a new interface called
>   ‘IMobileFactory’ and two concrete implementation’s ‘NokiaFactory’ and
>   ‘IphoneFactory’. These concrete classes control the object creation.
>
> In my example the client want a Nokia object. So the steps are given
>   below.
>
> 1.The client will load a reference to ‘NokiaFactory’. But Client won’t refer the ‘NokiaFactory’ class directly like the Simple Factory
>   pattern. The client refers the concrete implementation through an
>   interface ‘IMobileFactory’.
>
> 2.Then the Client call the ‘CreateMobile()’ method that will return an object of type ‘IMobile’.
>
> 3.Here we have to inform the client the concrete implementation to be used through some configuration or parameters.

I can't understand the first step:

> But Client won’t refer the ‘NokiaFactory’ class directly like the
>   Simple Factory  pattern. The client refers the concrete implementation
>   through an  interface ‘IMobileFactory’.

so client writes something like this:

```
IMobileFactory factory = LoadFactory("NokiaFactory");
```

so why is that useful and better? what's the benefit? why shouldn't I just write this:

```
NokiaFactory factory = new NokiaFactory();
```

or what about that:

```
IMobileFactory factory = new NokiaFactory();
```

Comment: Not really a fan of either; I would rather the author inject the reference to an `IMobileFactory` instance during the constructor call. Either way, the goal is to avoid directly referencing concrete classes and use interfaces. Using an interface will make your code more flexible for testing / new use cases because it is not coupled to a single implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So your question is about comparing this design #1:

```
IMobileFactory factory = LoadFactory("NokiaFactory");
```

to this design #2:

```
NokiaFactory factory = new NokiaFactory(); // or:
IMobileFactory factory = new NokiaFactory();
```

As you see the biggest difference is that, while the client in the design #1 does **not** know about any concrete type like `NokiaFactory` or `IPhoneFactory`, the client in the design #2 does.

The downside of knowing about concrete things like `NokiaFactory` or `IPhoneFactory` should be well-known. If you want to make changes to these types, for example, you want to add a new method to `NokiaFactory` and this method is not a part of the `IMobileFactory` interface, then the client code will be affected **unnecessarily**. The client does not care about the new method, but its code must be recompiled/redeployed.

### UPDATE

*To explain more.*

For example, a new method named `Foo` is added to the `NokiaFactory` class:

```
class NokiaFactory {
    // old code
    public void Foo() { ... }
}
```

`Foo` is not a method of the `IMobileFactory` interface but it is added to `NokiaFactory` because there is another client who requires the method, and that client is happy to depend on `NokiaFactory` class. In other words, that client would welcome changes from `NokiaFactory` class, but the first client would not.

Comment: I cant understand this part:  
"you want to add a new method to NokiaFactory and this method is not a part of the IMobileFactory interface, then client code will be affected unnecessarily". 
could you explain me this clearly?

Answer (score 5):

From the design perspective:

- Use SimpleFactory when the types of Objects are not fixed. For example: Phones my manufacturer - Nokia, iPhone. May be you want to add a new manufacturer tomorrow.
- Use Factory method when the types of Objects are fixed. For example: Phones by type - Landline and Mobile.

Finally, it comes down to how *you* want to design your system. What you want to be extendable.

Comment: https://www.binpress.com/factory-design-pattern/?fbclid=IwAR0Ix1EGTyqn1VyNJecAV6paPr1c3YFDqovs-3ZH5E_WF3hlLS0nSzEMsGo

according to this article it's vice-versa

Comment: As I understand the post, it says the same thing I mentioned here. Use Factory method for Toys by location and use SimpleFactory for Toys by type.

Comment: At first it seemed like you were saying the factory method is less extendable than simple factory. Then I realised factory method has a simple factory in every concrete factory, which makes my prior sentence impossible

Answer (score 1):

You need the interface to avoid creating different flow per type, for 10 types you will have 1 lines of code instead of 10

```
IMobileFactory factory = loadFactory(myFactoryName);
```

instead of per type:

```
NokiaFactory factory = new NokiaFactory();
...
IphoneFactory factory = new IphoneFactory();
...
```

The difference between using `loadFactory` method to `new  NokiaFactory()` is that you don't need to explicitly create a new object, you delegate object creation to  `loadFactory` which returns relevant object